# Output Geometry From ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer Coordinate System

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, map-service

Using ArcGIS for JavaScript 3.22 I am overlaying an ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer from a ArcGIS Server on top of ESRI basemap. While the service is published in the projected coordinate system with Spatial Reference: 102671  (3435) (NAD_1983_StatePlane_Illinois_East_FIPS_1201_Feet) the `eve.mappoint` returns the geometry coordinate in the spatial reference of Web Mercator or Geographic (4326) or 102100.

Can you please let me know how I can force the output to be in the Map Service projected format 102671  (3435) ?

Comment: Can you please show some of your code ?

Answer (score 1):

The projection of the published service doesn't matter here.  The projection is decided by the basemap's projection.  You cannot force a change in that.

You can either use a basemap in the projection you want your coordinates to be in, or, maybe preferably, use the geometry service to convert the `eve.mappoint` geometry coordinates to the spatial reference of your choice.